# iptables don't drop icmp packets

Tags: linux, iptables

I wanna block ping from outside the company to my server,
so I have the following iptables rules:

```
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s ! 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -d ! 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

However, the above rules aren't working as expected, I can still ping the server from both inside and outside the company.
What's wrong with that?!

Comment: The rules you posted don't give us any useful information. You need to post your complete ruleset including the default policy of each chain.

Comment: default policy for each chain is ACCEPT, and I haven't addded any other rules.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of source NAT is in use. Use something like `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to look at the ICMP packets the server is receiving when you ping it.

Comment: Please note that dropping **all** ICMP packets is not a good idea. (The content of you post says ping, the title is generic/all ICMP).

Comment: I also tried to remove " ! ", and then ping from inside failed, while from outside succeeded.

Comment: You probably have a router between  your server and Internet. These rules should be applied on router.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have 2 network interfaces, one to Internet and one for your local network.

Try something like this:

```
IPTABLES -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -i INTERNET_ETH -j DROP
```

The above will drop the `Echo Request` from the outside and I believe it is enough. After you see that the rule is working you play with source IP address. Also note the on the `INTERNET_ETH` interface ICMP requests with source address of 192.168.0.0/16 will not be received.

Good-Luck

Comment: my server has a customized OS, not a typical Linux/Unix machine. I can only find ifcfg-eth0, which maps to the mamagement port. therefore, your method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Is there a device in front of the server? Like a router or something else that might be responding to the ping?

```
iptables –A INPUT –p icmp –icmp-type echo-request -s ! 192.168.0.0/16 –j DROP
```

Should do it though.

Comment: -A is probably falling foul of an earlier accept rule

Answer (score 0):

try

```
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 ! -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Comment: -A is probably falling foul of an earlier accept rule

Comment: He said that no other rules were added.

Comment: not working at all... no difference to my rules, besides the position of the " ! "

Comment: Position of "!" is important.